# How to fix this error in react `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type

Tags: reactjs

I have this codes in react:

```
const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState("");

{
  catName.map((singleCategory, index) => {
    const { catName, _id: categoryId } = singleCategory;

    return (
      <>
        <div
          className="category-single-div flex-3 center-flex-align-display"
          key={index}
        >
          <p className="text-general-small2 category-custom-text">{catName}</p>
          <div className="category-icons-div ">
            <FaEdit
              className="category-icon-edit"
              onClick={() => {
                setEditCategory(true);
                setCategoryId(categoryId);
              }}
            />
            <AiFillDelete className="category-icon-edit category-icon-delete" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  });
}
```

I used map to get an array of objects, and I needed their individual `_id` when a user clicks the edit button. I also want to call another function on the same edit button via onClick. It is working but displays an error.

> Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a
> value of `string` type.

I need that `_id` so as to pass it to a state and have access to it globally within the component at the top level.
Is this workable?

Comment: Looks like there is no problem with the code you have attached. Include the complete error info with some screenshots and code where the error occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem comes from the FaEdit component.

```
            <FaEdit
              id={categoryId}
              className="category-icon-edit"
              onClick={(editCategory, id) => { // you need to have onClick as a prop defined inside the FaEdit component
                setEditCategory(editCategory);
                setCategoryId(id);
              }}
            />
```

Example...

```
export default function FaEdit({className, onClick, categoryId}){
    const handleChange() => {
       onClick(true, categoryId)
    }
    return(
    <div className={className} onClick={() => handleChange()}>Click</div>
    )
}
```